# git: assume unchanged bit not set

Tags: git

I have a file in my repo for which I tried setting the assume unchanged bit but it's still showing up in my unstaged file list. When I list all files for which the assumed unchanged bit is set, I get no files. Below are the steps I did.

```
/tmp/GitIssue on master ✗
❯ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   hi.txt
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

/tmp/GitIssue on master ✗
❯ git update-index --assume-unchanged hi.txt

/tmp/GitIssue on master ✗
❯ git ls-files -v | grep ^h | cut -c 3-

/tmp/GitIssue on master ✗
❯ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   hi.txt
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

This used to work in an earlier version of git(~1.6) on my laptop but not on the current version(2.4.4). Am I doing something wrong here or has something changed in the newer version related to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the actual behavior may have changed between versions, this is an implementation detail.  Fundamentally, `assume-unchanged` is a mechanism to allow Git to avoid hitting the filesystem to look for changes.  It means that Git *may* avoid looking at the files, it doesn't mean that Git *must* avoid looking at the files.

In particular, using the `assume-unchanged` bit is *not* a mechanism to make Git ignore the changes made to your files.

[From the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index):

> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).

I find the documentation a little bit passive on this topic.  Junio Hamano (the maintainer of git) [is more direct](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/246350):

> Assume-unchanged should not be abused for an ignore mechanism.  It 
>   is "I know my filesystem operations are slow.  I'll promise Git that 
>   I won't change these paths by making them with that bit---that way, 
>   Git does not have to check if I changed things in there every time I 
>   ask for 'git status' output".  It does not mean anything other than 
>   that.  Especially, it is *not* a promise by Git that Git will always 
>   consider these paths are unmodified---if Git can determine a path 
>   that is marked as assume-unchanged has changed without incurring 
>   extra lstat(2) cost, it reserves the right to report that the path 
>   *has been* modified (as a result, "git commit -a" is free to commit 
>   that change).